# MySQL in Ubuntu trying to user systemctl to start service

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, upstart

I have been using MySQL in Ubuntu for a long time, but yesterday, from the clear blue, the server would't start. It fails with the following message:

```
2013-12-20 10:03:28 - Executting '/bin/systemctl start mysqld'
2013-12-20 10:03:28 - Start server: /bin/bash: /bin/systemctl: File or Folder
2013-12-20 10:03:28 - Start server: not found.

2013-12-20 10:03:28 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
2013-12-20 10:03:29 - Server start done.
2013-12-20 10:03:29 - Checked server status: Server is stopped.
```

Investigating a little, I found out that systemctl is part of ([systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd)) package, which is not the default in Ubuntu 12.04... the default is **upstart**. That was all the info I could find around.

So the questions I have in my mind are:
1 - How came it that mysql is trying to use a different service to its initialization? Perhaps an update has broken it?
2 - How do I tell mysql server to use upstart to get started?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From google:  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/ There are also some man pages. Probably it wouldn't be a good idea to load systemd and use it in parallel to upstart but it might be fun to experiment.